# Boot on a modified iso image

Tags: debian, boot, iso, bootable

I try to modify an iso file, especially a debian installer (debian-11.4.0-i386-netinst.iso) , and boot on it.
The following code extract the content of an iso file and recreate a new iso file:

```
mkdir -p tmp_dir

bsdtar -C tmp_dir -xf debian-11.4.0-i386-netinst.iso

genisoimage -r -J -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat \
            -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table \
            -o new_image.iso tmp_dir
```

Then, I copied the new iso file on my USB stick:

`sudo dd if=new_image.iso of=/dev/sdg status=progress`

Then, `lsblk` gives the following output:

```
$ lsblk /dev/sdg
NAME MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sdg    8:96   1 29,4G  0 disk
```

But I cannot boot on it.
Do you know why?

Here some other information:

- First, I can boot on the USB stick if I create it with the original image:

`sudo dd if=debian-11.4.0-i386-netinst.iso of=/dev/sdg status=progress`

After that, `lsblk` gives me the following output:

```
$ lsblk /dev/sdg
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sdg      8:96   1 29,4G  0 disk 
├─sdg1   8:97   1  471M  0 part 
└─sdg2   8:98   1  1,9M  0 part
```

Note that we can see two partitions (I have no partition with the new image)

- Second, the new image works well on vmware. I don't really know it doesn't work with a standard machine.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The developer of the bootable-USB-media creator tool Rufus has written [this awesome answer on SuperUser.SE](https://superuser.com/a/1527373/432690) which describes the behind-the-scenes complexity that is causing your problems in a understandable way.

With `genisoimage`, you can only make the ISO file bootable as a (real or virtual) CD/DVD.

To boot it as a HDD-like device (i.e. when written to a USB stick), you need a Master Boot Record at the very beginning of the image, and it needs to include a valid MBR partition table, so the image can also be validly interpreted as a hard disk image.

This is sometimes known as an "isohybrid ISO image", according to the first tool that was developed to achieve that. On Debian 11, `xorriso` is capable of creating such image files.

With `xorriso -indev debian-11.4.0-i386-netinst.iso -report_el_torito cmd` and/or `xorriso -indev debian-11.4.0-i386-netinst.iso -boot_image any show_status`, you can have `xorriso` examine the original image and describe the boot structures on it as options you can feed back to `xorriso`. Here's what I got:

```
$ xorriso -indev debian-11.4.0-i386-netinst.iso -report_el_torito cmd
xorriso 1.5.2 : RockRidge filesystem manipulator, libburnia project.

xorriso : NOTE : Loading ISO image tree from LBA 0
xorriso : UPDATE :    1651 nodes read in 1 seconds
xorriso : NOTE : Detected El-Torito boot information which currently is set to be discarded
Drive current: -indev 'debian-11.4.0-i386-netinst.iso'
Media current: stdio file, overwriteable
Media status : is written , is appendable
Boot record  : El Torito , MBR isohybrid cyl-align-on GPT APM
Media summary: 1 session, 241152 data blocks,  471m data, 1781g free
Volume id    : 'Debian 11.4.0 i386 n'
-volid 'Debian 11.4.0 i386 n'
-volume_date uuid '2022070910381400'
-boot_image isolinux system_area=--interval:imported_iso:0s-15s:zero_mbrpt,zero_gpt,zero_apm:'debian-11.4.0-i386-netinst.iso'
-boot_image any partition_cyl_align=on
-boot_image any partition_offset=0
-boot_image any partition_hd_cyl=64
-boot_image any partition_sec_hd=32
-boot_image any mbr_force_bootable=on
-boot_image any apm_block_size=2048
-boot_image any iso_mbr_part_type=0x00
-boot_image any cat_path='/isolinux/boot.cat'
-boot_image isolinux bin_path='/isolinux/isolinux.bin'
-boot_image any platform_id=0x00
-boot_image any emul_type=no_emulation
-boot_image any load_size=2048
-boot_image any boot_info_table=on
-boot_image any next
-boot_image any efi_path='/boot/grub/efi.img'
-boot_image any platform_id=0xef
-boot_image any emul_type=no_emulation
-boot_image any load_size=2031616
-boot_image isolinux partition_entry=gpt_basdat
-boot_image isolinux partition_entry=apm_hfsplus
```

and

```
$ xorriso -indev debian-11.4.0-i386-netinst.iso -boot_image any show_status
xorriso 1.5.2 : RockRidge filesystem manipulator, libburnia project.

xorriso : NOTE : Loading ISO image tree from LBA 0
xorriso : UPDATE :    1651 nodes read in 1 seconds
xorriso : NOTE : Detected El-Torito boot information which currently is set to be discarded
Drive current: -indev 'debian-11.4.0-i386-netinst.iso'
Media current: stdio file, overwriteable
Media status : is written , is appendable
Boot record  : El Torito , MBR isohybrid cyl-align-on GPT APM
Media summary: 1 session, 241152 data blocks,  471m data, 1781g free
Volume id    : 'Debian 11.4.0 i386 n'
------------------------------------
Status of loaded boot image        :
------------------------------------
Boot record  : El Torito , MBR isohybrid cyl-align-on GPT APM
Boot catalog : '/isolinux/boot.cat'
Boot image   : '/isolinux/isolinux.bin' , boot_info_table=on
Boot image   : '/boot/grub/efi.img' , platform_id=0xEF 
------------------------------------
Boot image settings for next commit:
------------------------------------
-boot_image any discard
-boot_image any bin_path=''
-boot_image any emul_type=no_emulation
-boot_image any platform_id=0x00
-boot_image any boot_info_table=off
-boot_image grub grub2_boot_info=off
-boot_image any load_size=2048
-boot_image any sel_crit=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-boot_image any id_string=00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-boot_image isolinux partition_entry=off
-boot_image any appended_part_as=mbr
-boot_image any system_area=''
-boot_image any partition_offset=0
-boot_image any partition_sec_hd=0
-boot_image any partition_hd_cyl=0
-boot_image any partition_cyl_align=auto
-boot_image grub partition_table=off
-boot_image any mbr_force_bootable=off
-boot_image any appended_part_as=mbr
-boot_image any part_like_isohybrid=off
-boot_image any iso_mbr_part_type=default
-boot_image any gpt_disk_guid=random
-boot_image any chrp_boot_part=off
-boot_image any prep_boot_part=''
-boot_image any efi_boot_part=''
-boot_image any hfsplus_serial=0000000000000000
-boot_image any hfsplus_block_size=0
-boot_image any apm_block_size=0
------------------------------------
```

Most of the "magic" that makes the resulting ISO image bootable also when written on a USB stick is specified on the long line that starts with `-boot_image isolinux system_area=...`.

Anything that comes after `-boot_image any next` is related to UEFI support, and based on the boot options you used with your `genisoimage`, you might not care about that.

Comment: In addition to the very nice and complete answer of telcoM, this answer led me to the tool `isohybrid`. After having generated the new image `new_image.iso` with genisoimage, I simply ran `isohybrid new_image.iso`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @telcoM for your particularly complete answer.

I didn't succeed in building an EFI bootable AMD64 image of Debian, bootable in every situation (on a DVD or on a USB stick or...). Going back to the fundamentals, I found instructions for
[Repacking a Debian ISO with its original boot equipment](https://wiki.debian.org/RepackBootableISO).

Adapting the contents to 2023's ISO, I was able to write and sucessfully test the following procedure.

For the example, I will modify Debian 11.6 AMD64 stable ISO. I will add in its `/firmware` directory all firmware you can find on a Debian computer in `/usr/lib/firmware` after installing the following 3 Debian packages: `firmware-linux` `firmware-linux-free` `firmware-linux-nonfree`:

```
sudo apt install firmware-linux firmware-linux-free firmware-linux-nonfree
```

And after still for the example, I will repack the ISO, copying it on a USB key and successfully boot in legacy (MBR) and in UEFI mode
The image also work when burned on a DVD.

Make a root `mkiso` directory:

```
mkdir /home/nba/mkiso
cd /home/nba/mkiso
wget https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-dvd/debian-11.6.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso
```

Extract source ISO:

```
mkdir deb
sudo apt install xorriso
xorriso -osirrox on -indev deb11.6-nba-amd64.iso -extract / ./deb
```

or

```
sudo apt install bsdtar
bsdtar -C ./deb -xf debian-11.6.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso
```

Add files / firmware. We want to add firmware to the ISO image:

```
sudo apt install firmware-linux firmware-linux-free firmware-linux-nonfree

mkdir -p /home/nba/mkiso/fw
cp -rf /usr/lib/firmware /home/nba/mkiso/fw/
```

Extract xorriso build command from source ISO:

```
cat deb/.disk/mkisofs


xorriso -as mkisofs -r -checksum_algorithm_iso sha256,sha512 -V 'Debian 11.6.0 amd64 1' -o /srv/cdbuilder.debian.org/dst/deb-cd/out/3bullseyeamd64/debian-11.6.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso -checksum-list /srv/cdbuilder.debian.org/src/deb-cd/tmp/3bullseyeamd64/bullseye/checksum-check -jigdo-checksum-algorithm md5 -jigdo-force-checksum /pool/ -jigdo-min-file-size 1024 -jigdo-exclude 'README*' -jigdo-exclude /doc/ -jigdo-exclude /md5sum.txt -jigdo-exclude /.disk/ -jigdo-exclude /pics/ -jigdo-exclude 'Release*' -jigdo-exclude 'Packages*' -jigdo-exclude 'Sources*' -jigdo-jigdo /srv/cdbuilder.debian.org/dst/deb-cd/out/3bullseyeamd64/debian-11.6.0-amd64-DVD-1.jigdo -jigdo-template /srv/cdbuilder.debian.org/dst/deb-cd/out/3bullseyeamd64/debian-11.6.0-amd64-DVD-1.template -jigdo-map Debian=/srv/cdbuilder.debian.org/src/ftp/debian/ -jigdo-exclude boot1 -J -joliet-long -cache-inodes -isohybrid-mbr syslinux/usr/lib/ISOLINUX/isohdpfx.bin -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -no-emul-boot -eltorito-alt-boot -e boot/grub/efi.img -no-emul-boot -isohybrid-gpt-basdat -isohybrid-apm-hfsplus boot1 CD1
```

Modify xorriso build command (remove -jidgo options + related checksum...):

```
xorriso -as mkisofs -r -V 'deb11.6-nba-amd64' -o ./deb11.6-nba-amd64.iso -J -joliet-long -cache-inodes -isohybrid-mbr ./isohdpfx.bin -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -no-emul-boot -eltorito-alt-boot -e boot/grub/efi.img -no-emul-boot -isohybrid-gpt-basdat -isohybrid-apm-hfsplus deb fw
```

Generate MBR by extracting first 432 bytes from source ISO:

```
cd /home/nba/mkiso
dd if=debian-11.6.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso of=isohdpfx.bin bs=1 count=432
```

Build new iso (adding `deb/` and `fw/firmware` to the ISO):

```
xorriso -as mkisofs -r -V 'deb11.6-nba-amd64' -o ./deb11.6-nba-amd64.iso -J -joliet-long -cache-inodes -isohybrid-mbr ./isohdpfx.bin -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -no-emul-boot -eltorito-alt-boot -e boot/grub/efi.img -no-emul-boot -isohybrid-gpt-basdat -isohybrid-apm-hfsplus deb fw
```

Verify by extracting the newly created ISO:

```
mkdir /home/nba/mkiso/deb2
cd /home/nba/mkiso/
xorriso -osirrox on -indev deb11.6-nba-amd64.iso -extract / deb2
```

Verify firmware are present in `/home/nba/mkiso/deb2/firmware`:

```
ls /home/nba/mkiso/deb2/firmware
```

Test boot: use `xorriso -report_system_area` options on source ISO and on new ISO and compare:

```
xorriso -indev debian-11.6.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso -report_system_area as_mkisofs
xorriso -indev deb11.6-nba-amd64.iso -report_system_area as_mkisofs
```

Verify you have line:

```
-isohybrid-mbr --interval:local_fs:0s-15s:zero_mbrpt,zero_gpt,zero_apm:'deb11.6-nba-amd64.iso'
```

and lines:

```
-eltorito-alt-boot
-e '/boot/grub/efi.img'
-no-emul-boot
```

Copy to USB key and try to boot:

```
sudo dd if=deb11.6-nba-amd64.iso of=/dev/sda bs=256M status=progress
```

Reboot on key !